# Simplify the expression $\log_2({x_1}^{y_1} + {x_2}^{y_2})$ for large values of $x,y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, approximation

Following this thread:
[Simplify the expression $\log(2^x+2^y)$ for large values of $x,y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967845/simplify-the-expression-log2x2y-for-large-values-of-x-y)

Is there a way to simplify (or get a good approximation) for the $\log_2$ of a sum of powers with different bases?

Formally, I'm trying to simplify the following expression:
$\log_2({x_1}^{y_1} + {x_2}^{y_2})$, where $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$ (or in general for $x_1,...x_n$ and $y_1, ... y_n$), for cases where $y_1, y_2$ are very large and the power can't be computed.

Comment: With $\,x,y\gg1\,$ use $\,x+y\approx\max(x,y).$

Comment: @Somos It's possible but this is a too loose approximation if for instance $x \gg y$

Comment: Note $\log_2({x_1}^{y_1} + {x_2}^{y_2}) = \log_2\Big(2^{y_1\log_2(x_1)}+ 2^{y_2\log_2(x_2)}\Big)$ and use the methods in the linked thread.